# Get first hidden form and show it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't figure out how to get first `div` with class `form-wrapper` which is hidden and unhide it. What I want to accomplish is to create a button (Add Language) and when this button is clicked, show the first hidden div with class `form-wrapper`

[image]

What I've done: (the function unhideOneForm is called just once, for now, it's for testing purposes, but it does not show any form/div.

```
function unhideOneForm(){
    $(".form-wrapper :hidden:first").slideToggle("fast");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = $('.form-wrapper');
    $.each(divs, function(div){
        //alert($(this).html());
        if ($(this).find('select option:selected').text().indexOf("----") >= 0){

            $(this).hide()
        }
    });
    unhideOneForm()
});
```

Could you check where is the problem?

Comment: `$(".form-wrapper:hidden:first")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `display : none` is on your `<div class="form-wrapper">` and not its children.

So the selector should be,

```
$(".form-wrapper:hidden:first")
              //^ - remove the space - it is for child selector.
```